# Trouble with f90 major mode, maltreatment of highlighting in continuation lines

Tags: syntax-highlighting, fortran

My emacs (version 27.1 on a work computer where I do not have administrative privileges) seems strange. I am editing a *.f90 file and the major mode is correctly identified as f90. But the highlighting in continuation lines is off. Example:

```
PROGRAM test
  integer :: a, b, &
       c
END PROGRAM test
```

Variables a and b are highlighted in a reddish brown (as expected), but variable c is plain black. Is this normal or might there be something wrong with my setup? I have not customized anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to report a bug in Emacs, use `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

However, I recommend simply diving into the source and fixing it; it looks like continuation lines are fairly well–supported for indentation, but they don’t appear to be handled by the highlighting. If you look at `f90-font-lock-keywords-2`, for example, the first new item in this list is a regex matching variable declarations. It clearly matches everything up to an ampersand, exclamation, or newline character.